# Javascript inside php inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Scenario:
1. List of certain links in the format
  **Chapter - View(link) - Request access(link)**
2. Need to get chapter number and links from database and add in HTML

I'm trying to do as below. But it's not working. 
Value of i is not being evaluated in php code.
Can anyone please suggest me how to do it properly.

```
<script>
var total = "<?php echo $total; ?>";
var x=" ", i;
for (i=1; i<=total; i++) {

var chapter="<?php echo mysql_result($result,i,'chapter')?>"; 

    x=x+"<div> <a  href=' '>View</a>Status:<span class='status'> xxx</span><a  href=' '>Request Access</a></div>";
}
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: Do it at the top and pass the variables later.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix backend and frontend code to work with each other. PHP gets processed before it reaches the browser. JavaScript runs in the browser environment.

To my best guess, this is my fix for you

```
<script>
<?
$chapter = '';
$bulk = '';
for ($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++) {
    $chapter = mysql_result($result,$i,'chapter');
    $bulk .= "<div> <a href=' '>View</a>Status:<span class='status'> $chapter $i</span><a href=' '>Request Access</a></div>";
} 
?>
var x="<?=$bulk;?>";
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = x;
```

Your code seemed incomplete in your example as you didn't use chapter, I made my best guess on what you are trying to accomplish.